# Calculate temperature and precipitation by latitude

Tags: c#, latitude-longitude, temperature

Is there an algorithm to calculate average temperature by latitude? I googled for a long time but could only find this ([source](http://davidwaltham.com/global-warming-model/)):

```
T = To – a.sin^2λ
```

Where

```
T  = Temperature
To = Average equatorial temperature
a = a constant
λ = latitude.
```

But I have several problems with this:

- There is no mentioning of a source
- It's not mentioned what a is or what its value is
- Is the dot between a and sin ("a.sin") meant to be a
  multiplication sign?

So I was wondering if someone can explain if this algorithm is correct or if there is a better one, or none at all.
I found a confirmation for a basic relation of latitude and temperature [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Relationship_between_latitude_vs._temperature_and_precipitation.png):
[image]

I could use a lookup table (but I would have to generate it by some algorithm anyway), but I'd rather have a realtime calculation for certain reasons.

**So does anyone know if the algorithm above is correct, and can explain what the dot means?**

I would like to implement this in C#, but any language with a C-like syntax would be fine for me.

Bonus question: Any chance to cover precipitation in a similar way?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dot is multiplication, `a` I'm guessing is a constant related to the height over mean water level you want the temperature for. Latitude 30° mean temperature will be very different depending if its at water level or at 4000 feet.

Comment: This is not an algorithm, it's a formula. Although this is a well-researched question, it is off-topic for a programming Q&A site. I think the closest match on Stack Exchange is [Earth Science Q&A beta](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Anyways, there is very little use in this generalized formula. Temperature depends on many more variables that can drastically alter the theoretical "latitude temperature": inland, shoreline, middle of the ocean, mountain range, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a meteorological formula. Potential migration site is https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Well, thanks anyway for pointing out that I'm looking for a formula. Perhaps I will find more info with this new search keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, what you've given and are looking for is more of a formula than an algorithm, while you could argue it was an algorithm, algorithms usually refer to calculations involving conditionals or separate steps, not just a single non-complex calculation.

No, there is no such formula. To have a formula for average temperature would involve simulation all of the meteorological system.

Approximations are entirely possible however and that's what the above formula is. The dot in this instance is multiplication, the * operator in c#.

It should also be noted this is not the correct stack exchange for this question, the physics stack exchange would be more appropriate.